# How to Block all inbound and outbound traffic to and from an Local IP

Tags: networking, firewall, iptables, dd-wrt

I need to block entire traffic to and from an Local IP on an
WiFi Network, I am using DD WRT Based router, So I Can use
iptables. I know the IP Of an Client on the Local Network,
Some thing like 192.168.1.X, Now I need to filter And Drop all
the Traffic Originating From and Directed away from that IP,
So that He won't be able to use The Network. How can I do
this, Using iptables, If possible ?

Comment: It's very easy for a client to change its IP or even MAC address. If you're dealing with malicious attackers on your network, you need to look into Network Access Protection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're knowing the client's ip then you can use this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s **client_ip** -j DROP
iptables -I OUTPUT -d **client_ip** -j DROP
```

you can further refer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/479618/how-can-i-block-all-traffic-that-is-coming-to-and-from-an-ip-address-using-iptab)